# Spellchecking in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, spelling

I just switched from TexMaker to TexStudio - one of the main reasons is the improved spellchecker that lets you add words your ignore list directly (instead of manually modifying the .dic file, as you had to do with TexMaker).

All in all I am quite happy, but something is still bugging me. *TexStudio spellchecker does not ignore special characters.* So if I write...

```
The boy walked past the `house'.
                         ^^^^^^^
```

TexStudio will actually check for `house'.` and will not recognize it. Meaning I'll have to add every such combination to the ignore list manually.

Is there any way to **not** spellcheck special character-containing words?

And possibly ignore all LaTeX variables and command parameters too? Getting tired of the spellchecker also checking `htp!`, which is the placement parameter on image import commands... :/

---

P.S.
I am aware that some people prefer to write

```
The boy walked past the `house.'
```

but that is not really the discussion I'd like to get into here...

Comment: If `en_US` or `en_GB` is loaded I don't get the behavior you described. I get the behavior though if I switch to other dictionaries.

Comment: I am using `en_GB`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotation issue is a bug in the tokenizer. Will be fixed in the next release.

There are currently no options to configure the spellchecking options, like excluding options. You may add an entry to the feature request tracker:
http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/

Comment: I feared as much... Am I wrong or has this been an open issue for quite a while? I faintly remember writing a project report around 1-2 years ago and encountering the very same problem back then...

Comment: I opened a ticket on sourceforge, lets hope it gets fixed...