# Problems with TexStudio 2.7 spell checker

Tags: texstudio, spelling

I'm working with TexStudio 2.7, and trying to get the spell checker to work.

I've tried downloading a new dictionary (as in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/dictionary-for-texstudio-no-dictionary-available)), as well as modifying the .aff file (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96301/spellchecking-in-texstudio?rq=1)), but this doesn't seem to work..

It's not that the checker doesn't offer any corrections, but it's corrections are just not in English. Here are some of its offers:

1. algorithm -> Algorithmen, Algorithmus, algorithmisch
2. introduced -> eintrocknend
3. The -> Theo, Tee, Ehe, Che, Tue.

*****Any ideas as to why this happens and how to make it work?*****

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you set the standard language to "en_GB" or "en_US" ?
Please check under "options/configure TeXstudio/General" in section "Dictionaries"[image: standard language]

Answer (score 13):

1. You can set the **default dictionary** "options/configure TeXstudio/General". This will be used for all files (if you do not choose one of the options below to override it).
2. You can select the **current dictionary** of a file via the language selector in the status bar. This is a per-file setting and is not stored when closing the file. 
   [image: Language selector]
3. You can use a magic comment `% !TeX spellcheck = en_US` to **permanently assign a dictionary** to a file. TeXstudio checks for this comment when loading a file and automatically sets the current dictionary for the file accordingly.