# about the underscore appear in red color under text word

Tags: texstudio

when i write any word, a red colour underscore is appear under the word. 
This create  confusing a bad environment. Can anyone give me suggestion to remove the red underscore under word. I am using texeditor texstudio.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I guess this is the spell checker?

Comment: sir, underscore is appear at every word not a spell checker.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe. Perhaps, check `Syntax Highlighting` in `Options -> Configure TeX Studio` what is underscored in red.

Comment: @SonuRam if the spell checker does not understand the language you write in, it will highlight every word.

Answer (score 10):

Go to `Options -> Configure Tex Studio -> Syntax Highlighting`, there you see six columns with boxes (ticked or not). Look in the sixth column (`Wave underline`) and find a box that's ticked there, with a red box in one of the three boxes next to it. Uncheck that box and all your red wavy underlines will disappear.

I had this problem myself, and it is indeed the spell checker (as mentioned in the comments). I'm writing my document in English, and it accepts one paragraph completely, then for another it complains that "the" is misspelled. I'm a bit confused to as where TexStudio gets its spell checker from, it sure isn't consistent... To be honest, the red lines have never bothered me, and I didn't even notice them all until reading your question here.

**EDIT**

Add the following as the first line of your file. (I don't know what language you're writing in, this is for English.)

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
```

This sets the spell checker for this file to English, so unfortunately you'll have to add that to every file you write. I also found  [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195993/problems-with-texstudio-2-7-spell-checker)  question which has other solutions. The one where they set the default dictionary didn't work for me, as there's no `Dictionary` section in the `General` settings anymore. According to the  [TexStudio Manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html), section 1.4.1, there should be a `Default Language` option in the spell checker section, but that is missing here.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: At the very bottom there is a menu to select the language for the current file for the current session. This menu also provides a button `Insert language as TeX comment`. This button will insert the above mentioned line (for the currently selected language), so you do not need to remember the syntax.

Comment: For anyone now checking, Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Language Checking -> Default Language (this has a dropdown menu) select your language. For english, thats en_GB or en_US.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward. Follow the steps below

1. Open TexStudio
2. Go to `Options`
3. Choose `Configure TeXStudio`
4. Choose `Language Checking`
5. Change whatever language under the `Default Language` option to `<none>`

You are done!

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, go to preference and set the default language to en_US fixed my problem. It was previously set to Dutch or something, no wonder all the spell-check errors.

Answer (score 0):

[image: right bottom corner option]

1. (Right bottom corner of GUI) Click on the first option and choose language of choice. It will work fine.
2. The answer of adding "% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB" on top of each file works too.
3. The problem is because default language of GUI editor is German.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily by modifying some settings in the TeXstudio App. These are the steps.

1. First open TeXstudio App.
2. Go to Preferences.
3. Then Select Language Checking
4. Under the section Default language either choose your preferred language from one of the already available languages installed during installation or you can import one from LibreOffice or OpenOffice.
5. Click Okay and you are done.

This will remove all the red underlines from the TeXstudio editor.

Answer (score 0):

go to Edit--> Check Spelling while Type uncheck. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the setting that checks your spelling according to the language you use. The key here to change to the language that you are actually using.

1. Click `Options`
2. `Configure TeXstudio`
3. `Language Checking`
4. In `Spell Check` section: `Default Language`: `en_US` (or any other language of your choice)
5. Click `OK` at the button to save your changes to the settings.

Please make sure you don't remove the syntax highlighting as other answers may suggest by unchecking the `SpeelingMistake` checkbox. This may lead -eventually- to some mistakes and typos that you are not aware of. This feature should help you. I don't see the point of removing it!